# LinkedIn Company profile plugin is not working for some logged in users

Tags: linkedin-api

**I am posting it in Stackoverflow because LinkedIn [suggests](https://developer.linkedin.com/support) Stackoverflow with LinkeIn tag.**

In our web app, we are embedding LinkedIn's company profile widget using the code generated by Company Profile Plugin Generator https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile. This plugin doesn't display company profile info for some users if they are logged in to LinkedIn. If they log out, they can see the company profile.

Here is the code we are using in our site,

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="2089180" data-format="inline"></script>
```

Here is a sample page that exhibits this problem for some users,
http://plnkr.co/edit/mdURYh?p=preview

Any help to fix this would be appreiciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your reasons when you down vote. It will be helpful.

Comment: In our tests we saw this happening for **logged in users only**. We failed to recreate this in PC's or machines running Linux (Ubuntu). The *issue was succesfully recreated in Macs* and in one case on a Mac running Windows.

Please note that to verify this issue we tested on LinkedIn Company Profile widget creation page: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile

Comment: Furthermore, it should be noted that no JS errors appeared on the console. What was interesting was that when inspecting the Network panel to see what is going on, we noticed the `profile?companyIdentifier=....` call returning a 302 HTTP code and straight after a call to `secure_error?....` and then nothing.

Comment: Obviously adblock / ghostery / noscript and all other content-blocking extensions were turned off / disabled for this test.

Comment: This is a confirmed bug in the plugin at the moment.  There won't be a work-around available until a fix is released.

Comment: This was the result of a regression in the plugin code, not an error in your implementation.  It has been corrected now, and the plugin should be functioning normally once again.

Comment: @JustinKominar Thank you. We will test it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Perhaps the plugin isn't supported anymore? In any event, LinkedIn says:

[Promote your profile by adding a badge to your blog, online resume, or website:](https://www.linkedin.com/profile/profile-badges).

Several choices and the one I linked worked for me.